# Wait and Notify on same Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Is there anyway one single thread can wait and notify itself to "wake" up, or only

I got something like this but it isnt working and i get the illegalmonitorstateexception

```
public class test extends Thread{


private int n;
private int lim;

public test(int lim) {
    n = 0;
    this.lim=lim;
}

public synchronized void add() throws InterruptedException {
    n++;
    notify();
}


@Override
public void run() {

    while(n!=lim){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //do something
}

}

Main
```

Comment: While a thread `wait`s it can't do anything, including `notify`ing itself. The reason for the exception is that `wait` must be called inside a `synchronized` block. This is independent of the first problem.

Comment: By definition, while a thread is invoking `wait()`, it is not doing anything else.  Not even if it blocks in `wait()` for an extended period.  In particular, a `wait()`ing thread cannot `notify()` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IllegalMonitorStateException` means you "don't own the monitor". To do that:

```
synchronized (this) {
    wait()
}
```

What do you want to trigger the notification? As commented above, if a Thread is waiting, it can't take any action. Maybe you want to use a timeout?

Update:

To `wait()` until `lim` is reached, add this to the `add()` method:

```
if (n >= lim) {
    notify();
}
```

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, what you want is a *different* thread to call the `add()` method, thus notifying the waiting thread to wake up and continue.

Comment: ... and the thread that invokes `add()` must take ownership of the monitor to successfully invoke `notify()`, whether inside the `add()` method or outside, so that the invocation is protected by the monitor.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, the method is `synchronized`, so that's ok.

Comment: ah, yes.  I overlooked that.

Comment: What im trying to do is have a thread in "wait" until lim is reached, Tried creating another object, will edit the post

Comment: @Ventura updated my answer to cover waiting until `lim` is reached

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here appears to be with the idea of "notifying a thread". You don't (usually) call `notify`, `notifyAll` or `wait` of a `Thread` object. Invoke it any object that you are using as a lock. (A particular problem with `Thread` is that it is used as a lock for a particular purpose already (`Thread.join`).)

So you need some kind of lock object:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

To wait on the object, you need to hold the lock and the condition should be checked in a `while` loop.

```
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (!some_condition) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        ...
    }
```

To notify, hold the lock, notify (you might as well go for `notifyAll`, it'll be at least as good as `notify` and sometimes it may be necessary but not caught in testing) and change the condition.

```
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notifyAll();
        some_condition = true;
    }
```

Also, it good practice not to subclass `Thread`. Goes for other unnecessary subclassing too. Typically you would create a `Runnable` and pass it to the constructor.